# Is there clean syntax for checking if multiple variables all have the same value?

Tags: java

We have n variables `X = {x1,x2,...xn}` they are not in any structures whatsoever.

In python for example I can do that: `if (x1 == x2 == x3 == xn):`

In java I must do: `if((x1 == x2) && (x2 == x3) && (x3 == xn)):`

Do you know a simple way to improve this syntax? (Imagine very long variable name and lot of them)

Thanks.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but this cries out for some kind of data structure instead of a bunch of independent variables.

Comment: in java, (x1 == x2 == x3 == x4) will returnTest.java:8: incomparable types: boolean and int
 System.out.println(x1 == x2 == x3 == x4);
                             ^
Test.java:8: incomparable types: boolean and int
 System.out.println(x1 == x2 == x3 == x4);

Comment: I said in python we can do that (x1 == blabla) what's your point Leo?

Comment: @Leo that's even more dangerous if you're trying to do that with a set of booleans. If x1,x2,x3,x4 are booleans, they will compile but have a silent bug. `x1 == x2 == x3` says `(x1 == x2) == x3` whhich is VERY different than what we want!

Comment: @TomZych Is it possible to write $ a<b<c $ ? or should we write $ a<b && b<c && ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you have lots of these variables, have you considered putting them in a collection instead of having them as separate variables? There are various options at that point.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might want to write helper methods, possibly using varargs syntax. For example:

```
public static boolean areAllEqual(int... values)
{
    if (values.length == 0)
    {
        return true; // Alternative below
    }
    int checkValue = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] != checkValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

An alternative as presented by glowcoder is to force there to be at least one value:

```
public static boolean areAllEqual(int checkValue, int... otherValues)
{
    for (int value : otherValues)
    {
        if (value != checkValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In either case, use with:

```
if (HelperClass.areAllEqual(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think `areAllTheSame()` should return true. Currently it will choke on `values[0]` i suppose.

Answer (score 13):

You could create a utility method like this:

```
public boolean allEqual(Object... objs) {
    if(objs.length < 2) return true; // 0 or 1 objects are all equal
    Object key = objs[0]; // pick one
    for(Object o : objs) if(!o.equals(key)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Another option would be

```
public boolean allEqual(Object key, Object... objs) {
    for(Object o : objs) if(!o.equals(key)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

To simplify a lot of boilerplate logic. Then just go

```
if(allEqual(x,x1,x2,x3))
```

Obviously the two are mutually exclusive (they are signaturely ambigous) but you could have
`allEqual` and `allEqualWithKey`

Comment: @glowcoder: I considered this form too... but boxing all the values could end up being a bit painful. I think for the sake of a few overloads, I'd treat each primitive type separately.

Comment: +1 @Jon, though this has the benefit of being more reusable. Depends on the application, I suppose.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: I'd be surprised to see this required for more than a few types, to be honest. I do like the "force at least one argument" bit though :)

Comment: Thank you all for your time! btw my objects are ArrayLists and I'm checking their size. I've learn more in these last 10 minutes than during the last hour, wondering the web for answers. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jon I agree. That would be advisable not just for performance concerns, but for functionality: you may want to have a margin of error for floating point values.

Comment: @glowcoder: Very good point. Another option would be to make it generic, and also pass in something to represent the equality operation. That's probably gilding the lily though :)

Comment: @Jon I can see the code review now. "What's this anonymous Comparator object and what does it do?" Oh that defines the comparison for the allEqual utility. "What does that do?" Oh it saves us from writing boilerplate code!

Answer (score 8):

Similar to @Jon's solution but shorter.

```
public static boolean areAllTheSame(int value, int... values) {
    for (int i: values) if(value != i) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Half of the reason that's shorter is putting lots of stuff on one line and not using braces - which I'd never do in production code. I've edited in the "force at least one argument" version into my code though, as originally shown by glowcoder.

Comment: @Jon I wrote this before I saw your edit. I am not in favour of padding out the code with lots of { } on new lines. However I would only use one liners line this for the simplest of operations.

Comment: It's not "padding out code" - it's keeping things absolutely clear, IMO. Having been bitten by an "indentation was lying, that's an if statement with a single statement after it, then another statement" bug once, I'm not about to repeat the same mistake. Of course, you could put the open brace at the end of the leading line...

Comment: @Jon I tend to use the IDE to highlight when the identation is lying. This is feature is turned on for all our developers. ;)  I agree that; you should do what you believe is clearest.  I tend to find the less symbols the better (although I prefer meaningful names for things)

Answer (score 5):

You could write a method that makes this look less cumbersome:

```
boolean areAllEqual(Object... values) {
    if (values.length < 2) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (!values[i].equals(values[0])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (areAllEqual(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)) {
    // do something
}
```

*edit* Too slow...! :-(

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, there's no syntactic sugar available. This is a common gripe about Java.

Comment: Hm, perhaps it was only common at my university then? Thanks for the alternate point of view, @Jon.

Comment: Never needed this in several years of Java. Cute, but there are many other places the syntax drive me more crazy :)

Comment: If I had to choose between this and closures... :)

Comment: I think a related and possibly more common sugar request is for something like `if(0 < x < 10)` to replace `if(0 < x && x < 10)`.

Comment: what do u mean by `syntactic sugar` ?

Comment: @Deepak, "Syntactic sugar is a computer science term that refers to syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express, while alternative ways of expressing them exist." -[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Comment: For the downvoter, and future downvoters: I considered deleting this post, but the title and body both specifically ask about syntax, not a clever algorithm for checking equality. The original title was slightly more explicit, if anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
* reference - basic String to compare against
* entries - all other objects for comparison
*/
public static boolean allEqual(String reference, String... entries) {
        return Arrays.stream(entries)
                .allMatch(entry -> Objects.equals(reference, entry));
}

/*
* Method can be generalized to use <T> instead of String
*/
public static <T>boolean allEqual(T reference, T... entries) {
    return Arrays.stream(entries)
            .allMatch(entry -> Objects.equals(reference, entry));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(allEqual("X", "X", "X", "X")); // true
    System.out.println(allEqual("X", "X", "Y"));      // false
    System.out.println(allEqual("X"));                // true

    System.out.println(allEqual(10, 10, 9));          // false
    System.out.println(allEqual(10, 10));             // true
    System.out.println(allEqual(10, new Integer[] {10, 10, 10})); // true
}
```

Comment: Nice to see that someone is still answering old questions and provides up to date answers. It would be even nicer if you could add some explanation on how to use your method and how it works.

Comment: Sorry, didn't think about explanation. I have updated snippet. I hope it is more readable now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like typing, you could lose the nested paretheses:

```
if(x1 == x2 && x2 == x3 && x3 == xn);
```

Comment: You're right sorry. I misinterpreted operator precedence [link](http://www.uni-bonn.de/~manfear/javaoperators.php)

Answer (score 1):

Another quick way to achieve this would be via the `array` -> `List` -> `HashSet` conversion route, as in:

Standard Java:

```
if(new HashSet<Object>(Arrays.asList(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)).size() == 1) {

}
```

Google Guava:

```
if(Sets.newHashSet(Ints.asList(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)).size() == 1) {

}
```

The aforementioned solution doesn't look too clean in it's own right, though, so it should definitely be isolated into a separate utility method with a sensible name (in which case you'd probably be better off with Peter Lawrey's or Jon Skeet's solution in the first place).

I'd also expect this approach to be associated with at least a tiny performance hit, since it's clear that multiple `Collection`s have to be instantiated & populated.

So to reiterate - only use this solution if you are hell-bent on hitting a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 this can be done as a one-liner using a `Stream`:

```
boolean allEqual = Stream.of(x1, x2, x3, x4).distinct().count() == 1;
```

Basically `distinct` filters the stream by checking each element for equality, so that only unique elements remain. If there is exactly one element left after filtering, it means all original elements are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I like the boilerplate logic that has already been suggested, but typically any of the arguments in the list can be `null`, which could cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown. We should therefore test for `null` first and use `==` to compare object references where appropriate:

```
public static boolean allEqual(Object key, Object... objs) {
    for(Object o : objs)
        if((key != null && !key.equals(o)) || key != o) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note that ```Object... objs``` needs at least two arguments to be interpreted as an array given a single ```null``` value. So, in the case of two-value comparisons use standard java commands, or alternatively add the following to the beginning of the method ```objs = objs == null ? new Object[]{ null } : objs;```

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils
public static boolean and(final boolean... array)

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring these answers up to date (Java SE 9).

```
 Set.of(x1,x2,...xn).size() == 1
```

Makes perfect sense to a mathematician. (I am calling myself a mathematician in this context.)

(Obviously, there are boxing overheads of one sort of another for the `Integer`s, `Integer[]`, `Set` and, potentially, internally to the `Set`.)

**Edit:** Stuart Marks points out that `Set.of` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if there are duplicate elements. Alternative:

```
Set.copyOf(Arrays.asList(x1,x2,...xn)).size() == 1
```

or depending on your definition of clean:

```
copyOf(asList(x1,x2,...xn)).size() == 1
```

(Assumes excessive static imports.)

Answer (score -2):

Using the following code snipped you can identify `Map` values with duplicates:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 1;
        int d = 3;

        Collection<Integer> collectionOfValues = List.of(a, b, c, d);

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupedByUniqueKeys = collectionOfValues.stream()
            .collect(
                groupingBy(
                    Function.identity()));

        System.out.println(groupedByUniqueKeys);
        // {1=[1, 1], 2=[2], 3=[3]}
    }
```

The mapping for key `1` will contain values for the variables with equal values (`a` and `c`).

Comment: But that wasn't the question.