# Kotlin: How to check if all values in the sequence has same value

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to write a helper method in Kotlin which would check if all the values in a sequence has the same value.

Thanks to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503091/is-there-clean-syntax-for-checking-if-multiple-variables-all-have-the-same-value/5503154)

Java Style code in Kotlin using `Streams` works as seen below

```
fun <T> allEqual(vararg entries: T): Boolean {

    val reference = entries[0]
    return Arrays.stream(entries)
        .allMatch { entry: T -> reference == entry }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(allEqual("EUR", "USD", "USD", "EUR")) //returns false
    println(allEqual("USD", "USD", "USD", "USD")) //returns true
}
```

Been trying to achieve the same in `Kotlin` using `sequences` and also I want to keep this helper function generic.

```
fun <T> isAllEqual(vararg entries: T) : Boolean {
    val reference = entries[0]
    println(reference)
    val isEqual: (Array<out T>) -> Boolean = { it == reference }
   val seq = listOf(entries).asSequence()
    return seq.all{isEqual}
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(isAllEqual("USD", "USD", "USD", "USD"))
}
```

I see the following error `Type mismatch. Required: (Array<out T>) → Boolean Found: (Array<out T>) → (Array<out T>) → Boolean`

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
fun <T> allEqual(vararg entries: T): Boolean = entries.all { it == entries[0] }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, there is no reason to create a sequence. Also, if you want to keep your `println` statement you could use `apply` like this: `entries.apply { println(first()) }.all { it == entries.first() }`. Note `.first()` is the same as `fizz[0]`